# Database not showing on first opening the app

Tags: android, sqlite

I made an android application which saves notes. The notes are indeed saved. However when the app is opened only the example note `Akhilesh Chobey` is shown. All other notes are shown on pressing the back button in the `Main2Activity`(Activity for editing note)

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView notesListView;
static ArrayList<String> notesArrayList;
static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesListView);
    notesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(Main2Activity.myDb != null) {
        notesArrayList.clear();
        Cursor res = Main2Activity.myDb.getData();
        if (res.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.i("Error", "error");
            return;
        }
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            notesArrayList.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("text")));
        }
    }

    notesArrayList.add("Akhilesh Chobey");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notesArrayList);
    notesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    notesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("notePosition", i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Main2Activity:**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {

static DatabaseOperations myDb;
EditText editNote;
int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    editNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);

    myDb = new DatabaseOperations(Main2Activity.this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    position = intent.getIntExtra("notePosition", -1);
    if(position != -1){

        editNote.setText(MainActivity.notesArrayList.get(position));

    }
    editNote.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if (myDb != null) {
        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editNote.getText().toString());        


        MainActivity.notesArrayList.set(position, String.valueOf(charSequence));
        MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Database Helper Class:**

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DatabaseName = "notes.db";
public static final String TableName = "notes";
public static final String Col1 = "text";

public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseName, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TableName + " (text TEXT) ");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableName);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String note){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Col1, note);

    long result = db.insert(TableName, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TableName, null);
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Getting reference to db helper from another Activity looks weird for me.
I suppose that    if(Main2Activity.myDb != null) {
        notesArrayList.clear();
        Cursor res = Main2Activity.myDb.getData();
        if (res.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.i("Error", "error");
            return;
        }
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            notesArrayList.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("text")));
        }
    }
this is the problem and db is returned null so you do not load date from db.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make the database `myDb` "not null" ?

Comment: Create new instance inside Activity1
myDb = new DatabaseOperations(this);

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rafal. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

in your Main2Activity class(Terrible naming BTW) the

`static DatabaseOperations myDb;`

variable is not assigned with anything at the start of the program, so `DatabaseOperations== null`, so the if condition

```
if(Main2Activity.myDb != null) {
    notesArrayList.clear();
    Cursor res = Main2Activity.myDb.getData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.i("Error", "error");
        return;
    }
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        notesArrayList.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("text")));
    }
}
```

will not be executed thus no data will be loaded in to the app. 
**BUT** when you come back from the M2A class by pressing back 
onCreate is called once again but this time `DatabaseOperations myDb != NULL` ,because myDb is assigned a value by this,

`myDb = new DatabaseOperations(Main2Activity.this);`
 so the if condition in MainActivity class becomes true.

**WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO:** find a way to make that myDb variable not null at the start of the program.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree, terrible naming. But I could not think of any way to make it 'not null'

Comment: is really really necessary to use that Main2Activity.myDb != null part? coz from my perspective that DB handling part should be in some other class that handles all the DB things, Do Not use activity class to do all the Logical things, Ever heard of MVC pattern ?? this is perfect situation for MVC.

Comment: You could use static blocks but i really deprecate that option,

Comment: Not quite following you. I tried removing the `if(Main2Activity.myDb != null)` condition. But it results in a crash.

Comment: of course it should you are calling Cursor res = Main2Activity.myDb.getData(); on a null myDb variable

Comment: This will work (I guess) put following code into MainActivity class 1)static DatabaseOperations myDb; 2) inside onCreate() and before the if condition: myDb = new DatabaseOperations(MainActivity.this);